# Does Kvothe ever use the bed Auri prepared for him?

Tags: patrick-rothfuss, the-kingkiller-chronicle

In Slow Regard of Silent Things, one of the gifts Auri prepares for Kvothe is a bed of his own near hers in the Underthing, along with a candle and a kiss.

I've just finished a re-read of both The Name of the Wind and Wise Man's Fear, and while I found references to her giving him the candle and the kiss and letting him know that there is always a safe place for him to stay with her, I wasn't sure if he ever made use of it.

Does he ever stay with Auri in the Underthing, making use of that third gift?

Comment: I don't *think* so, but it might happen in book 3. ([Not out yet](https://twitter.com/isbook3outyet) `:-(`)